# In clause in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have select query like this

```
SELECT * FROM ACTITIVY WHERE CODE in ('L','D')
```

Instead of hardcording the values in IN PARAMETER I have created a PARAM table. The param table has the below values

```
CODE         |   CODE_VAL  | ACTIVE 
TRIGGER_XM   |  'L','D'    |   Y
```

so when i rewrite the query as below

```
select * from ops_ACTITIVY WHERE CODE IN  ( 
SELECT CODE_VAL FROM OPS_CONFIG_PARAMETER 
WHERE CODE='TRIGGER_XML' AND ACTIVE='Y')
```

It doesn't work any idea how to resolve this??

Comment: which table are you really using? `ACTITIVY` or `ops_ACTITIVY`?

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
select * from ops_ACTITIVY t1
WHERE t1.CODE IN ( SELECT CODE_VAL FROM OPS_CONFIG_PARAMETER t2 
WHERE t2.CODE='TRIGGER_XML' AND t2.ACTIVE='Y' )
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are checking for the existence of a string inside another string you could try something like this:

```
select * from activity a where (
    select instr(b.code_val, a.code)
    from param b
    where b.code = 'TRIGGER_XM'
    AND active = 'Y'
) > 0;
```

But it will most likely only work as long as as you have singlechar codes.

Worked for me at: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3e68/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

which table are you really using? `ACTITIVY` or `ops_ACTITIVY`?

Assuming that those tables are the same, i would suggest that your PARAMETERS Table have the below values:

```
| CODE          | CODE_VAL  | ACTIVE    |
| -----------   ----------- -------------
| TRIGGER_XM    | L         | Y         |
| TRIGGER_XM    | D         | Y         |
```

It is much more manageable, and i think makes much more sense to separate the Code Values of L and D in case you only need to select one of them.

Now, the query below would surely fetch both Codes with 'L' and 'D' values from the `ops_ACTITIVY` table:

```
select  * 
from    ops_ACTITIVY 
WHERE   CODE IN (SELECT CODE_VAL 
        FROM    OPS_CONFIG_PARAMETER 
        WHERE   CODE ='TRIGGER_XML'
        AND     ACTIVE = 'Y');
```